# Su doesn't work - Raspbian

Tags: user, su, raspbian

I'm installing an OrangePi (more powerful than the Rasp one). After installing the system with the default root user only I would like to add a new user and connect from ssh

```
adduser foobar
```

I got all the files created `/home/foobar`

But I cannot switch user

```
# su foobar
#
```

Also when I try to connect from ssh

```
ssh foobar@ip
```

The connection close right after.

If I `ssh -v -v -v foobar@ip`

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.111 [192.168.1.111] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.111:22 as 'gil'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/ragnar/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/ragnar/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.111
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:y4fZzMo5EBbBgz1Bs+C02avtDWUpAADjHmAhIyM+MTM
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/ragnar/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/ragnar/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.111
debug1: Host '192.168.1.111' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/ragnar/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fd1a2d00420),
debug2: key: /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/ragnar/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
gil@192.168.1.111's password:
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.111 ([192.168.1.111]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env COMMAND_MODE
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XPC_FLAGS
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env SECURITYSESSIONID
debug3: Ignored env ITERM_PROFILE
debug3: Ignored env XPC_SERVICE_NAME
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env ITERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env ZSH
debug3: Ignored env PAGER
debug3: Ignored env LESS
debug3: Ignored env LSCOLORS
debug3: Ignored env EDITOR
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Linux orangepi 3.4.39 #20 SMP PREEMPT Sat May 2 16:01:42 HKT 2015 armv7l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Sat Dec 26 17:45:24 2015 from gils-macbook-pro.home
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-signal reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

Connection to 192.168.1.111 closed.
Transferred: sent 3440, received 2240 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 181954.0, received 118481.7
debug1: Exit status -1
```

I make 2 different user just to try both fail `/etc/passwd`

```
gil:x:1002:1006:Gil,,,:/home/gil:/bin/zsh
toto:x:1000:1004:,,,:/home/toto:/bin/bash
```

and

```
/var/log/auth.log' returns
'Dec 27 08:25:26 orangepi su[2877]: Successful su for gil by root
Dec 27 08:25:26 orangepi su[2877]: + /dev/pts/0 root:gil
Dec 27 08:25:26 orangepi su[2877]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user gil\
 by root(uid=0)
Dec 27 08:25:26 orangepi su[2877]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user gil
```

Any idea ?

Comment: If your prompt is actually `#` as in the example you've shown, then you're already root.

Comment: Do `/bin/bash` and `/bin/zsh` exist?

Comment: I don't want to be root. I want to be my user. I cannot login as user with ssh or with the good old keyboard at login screen.
@Paul yes bash and zsh exist.

Comment: What linux distribution did you install?

Comment: I install Raspbian

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering, not commenting.
The situation you showed happens because user `foobar` doesn't have a default shell.

To check it, try running `su` this way: `su -s /bin/bash foobar` as root.

If `foobar@pi` and the dollar sign appear then my answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but like I said in the comment of my questions, The user I created has a default shell :
`/etc/passwd`
`gil:x:1002:1006:Gil,,,:/home/gil:/bin/zsh`
I created a new one with bash as default. I cannot login too.

Your command doesn't work either. But thanks.